# Singleton destroy in different platforms

Tags: android, c++, linux, windows, cross-platform

This code work perfectly in Windows and Linux, but in Android don’t calling appCfg::~appCfg().How modify code to destroy appCfg automatically (on close program) in all platforms?

.cpp

```
appCfg * appCfg::p_instance = 0;
SingletonDestroyer appCfg::destroyer;

SingletonDestroyer::~SingletonDestroyer() {  
    delete p_instance;
}
void SingletonDestroyer::initialize( appCfg* p ) {
    p_instance = p;
}

appCfg& appCfg::getInstance() {
    if(!p_instance)     {
        p_instance = new appCfg();
        destroyer.initialize( p_instance);    
    }
    return *p_instance;
}

appCfg::appCfg()
{
    pSetting = new QSettings(Const::SettingPath()+"/main.cfg",QSettings::IniFormat);
}
//called on Windows and Linux platforms, but not on Android    
appCfg::~appCfg()
{
    pSetting->sync();
    delete pSetting;
}

...
```

Comment: Why are you returning a reference to the **value** of the pointer, in your getInstance method? Basically you are not returning anything related to **p_instance** pointer whatsoever.

Comment: @ozur. p_instance initialized on first call getInstance()

Answer (score -1):

All the code does not fit, so I write the rest here

.h

```
class SingletonDestroyer
{
private:
    appCfg* p_instance;
public:   
    ~SingletonDestroyer();
    void initialize( appCfg* p );
};

class appCfg : public QObject
{
private:
    static appCfg* p_instance;
    static SingletonDestroyer destroyer;

    QSettings * pSetting;
protected:
    appCfg();
    appCfg( const appCfg& );
    appCfg& operator=( appCfg& );
    ~appCfg();
    friend class SingletonDestroyer;
public:
    static appCfg& getInstance();
   ...
};
```

Comment: @ Selvin. All the code does not fit, so I write the rest in answer